# Gradient Boosting Paper Understanding

Tags: self-study, cart

I am reading Gradient Boosting paper [link](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~jhf/ftp/trebst.pdf). I need some examples to understand the following statement:

> Suppose for particular loss function L(y,F) and/or base learner h(x;
>   a) the solution to (9) is difficult to obtain.

I am not sure of examples/scenarios in which directly optimizing equation (9) is difficult.

Comment: Interesting paper, I think I am going to check this out since I'm interested in data science. To answer your question, I would think it would be difficult to optimize equation(9) if the loss function was not smooth and continuous. Kind of like when you are trying to obtain a maximum likelihood estimation when the function is not smooth(so you cant just differentiate). You have to employ numerical approximations like newton-raphson or fisher scoring to find an approximate numerical maximum(which may be local or global).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about something like "Hinge loss", with any base learner. In the case you don't have a point to start your search, you may be stuck for a long time in the region where the hinge loss gradient vanishes.

Or the function h may be expansive to evaluate, it may take a while to solve (9).